# No Sound on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: sound, 14.04, default, reset

I am completely new to Ubuntu. I wasn't hearing the notification on skype and started to mess around with the settings.Now I dont have any sound at all I started installing and removing packages like pulseaudio and I really don't know what I have done? Is there a way just to set everything back to default? please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this,](http://www.kingletas.com/2012/07/restore-ubuntu-to-the-default-settings-without-re-installing-it.html) but make sure you backup all the files you wouldn't want to lose.